# Set time to stop in activity indicator while loading if it takes time to long to response swift 3

Tags: swift, loading, uiactivityindicatorview

**Swift 3 iOS 10:** I want set the time interval to stop activity indicator if it's too long to responsd. When there is no response, it will be loading forever. Therefor, how can I stop it in the middle of the way?

Answer (score 0):

if

```
activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
```

, then the moment you stop the activityIndicator, it should work, regardless of when. Otherwise provide some code so I can see the problem.

Comment: The moment I start, I use  `UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()` function to disable user interaction, so user cant do anything while loading such as pressing button to stop.

Comment: @EKChhuon why would you need to do that; why not add an overlay(a custom UIView with a black background alpha set to 0.6) underneath the activity indicator so that way you can add a stop button on top of the custom UIView that would enable the user to press stop

Comment: I dont want user able to tab anything while loading, that's why i use that

Comment: @EKChhuon that's the purpose of adding a UIView overlay, you can add it on top of everything that is touchable